# Enable plugin in devMode

Tags: plugins, devmode

Is is possible to enable certain plugins only in devMode? (or via some other configuration option)?

Comment: I made a question / [FR] out of this: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/5107

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just was pointed to the correct solution (shame on me I did not find it myself):

There already is a config for this:
https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#disabledplugins

To be used like this:

```
'production' => [
     'disabledPlugins' => ['cloner', 'cp-field-inspect', 'dumper', 'migration-manager']
],
```

Thanks gtettelaar for dropping me a hint! (https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/5107)

Answer (score 1):

No.

However if you explain more, and the reasons why you want to do this, there might be a solution.

EDIT: Based on comment

As part of my deployment, I would have a diiferent composer.json file for the production environment which would only contain the plugins you want.

Then run `composer update` on production. Only what you want will be included.

Comment: OK: There are certain plugins, which are useful for development, e.g. 
"CP Field Inspect" (which shows field handles when editing entries), but not for production. I do not want to load those plugins, when in devMode, or alternatively when ENV = production or something like that.

Comment: As a response to your changed answer: I also thought about that. But then you always need to re-enable the plugin when you clone the live database to your local one.

Comment: @MatthiasRedl-Mann my deployments are all scripted, so it is possible to run `./craft install/plugin PLUGINNAME` to automate that also

Comment: same for me, but this does not solve my problem: I either always need to re-enable the plugin locally after having drawn a dump or I need to script this. It's simply the wrong direction.... thanks anyway